# How can I make PrintWriter NOT append to a file?

Tags: java, file

I have a server that writes to a logfile, but I do not want to append lines. I have set the flag to false, but still it seems to be appending. How can I make it REPLACE the first line everytime so my file contains one updated line everytime ?

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename), false);
PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
..
..
while(true){
  line = getRandomLine();
  bw.println(line);
  bw.flush();
}
..
..
```

Comment: If I open the `fos` with `false`, it overrides the old content of the file. Reported unexpected behavior not reproducible, please provide a more complete [mcve].

Comment: Replace the first line? Why? If you really want a one-line file you will have to open and close it inside this loop

Comment: If we have remove the one level decoration and create writer object with below does it still gives issues?? pw new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt", true)); }

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "If I open the fos with false, it overrides the old content of the file", this doesn't happen

Comment: @TrtTrt This definitely *does* happen on my pretty much average debian-based linux distro with openjdk 1.8.0. If this doesn't happen on your system, then you probably should provide much more information about your OS and java installation. I doubt that it behaves any differently, unless you're trynig to run it on some super-obscure self-built operating system with a custom jvm implementation that does not fully comply with the specification.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly, you want this:

```
File file = new File(filename);

while (true) {
    pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    line = getRandomLine();
    pw.println(line);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: Use try-with-resources, and there is no need for `flush()` before `close()`.

Comment: wouldn't "pw = new PrintWriter(file);" be slow in a while loop?

Comment: It would but I don't think that fast and easy way exists.